# Angular Material - Not rendering components properly

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to use a form field from Angular Material.

And it's supposed to look kinda like this:
[image]

but instead it looks like this:
[image]

The code I have so far:

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatToolbarModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatButtonModule, MatCardModule, MatMenuModule, MatIconModule } from '@angular/material';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatIconModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

login.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { usuario } from "../_modelos/usuario.model";

import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  email = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]);

    getErrorMessage() {
      return this.email.hasError('required') ? 'You must enter a value' :
          this.email.hasError('email') ? 'Not a valid email' :
              '';
    }

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

login.component.html:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <span>Sign in</span>
  <span class="example-spacer"></span>
  <img width="200" src="../assets/Logo_2.png">
</mat-toolbar>

<div class="example-container">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput placeholder="Enter your email" [formControl]="email" required>
      <mat-error *ngIf="email.invalid">{{getErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
```

login.component.css:

```
.example-spacer {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
  }
  .example-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .example-container > * {
    width: 100%;
  }
```

I got the code from the official website of Angular Material.

Comment: Did you import a prebuilt theme somewhere, like in an existing css file?

Comment: Yes, i have this in the "styles.css": import '~https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons';
import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to import `MatInputModule` to your app: https://material.angular.io/components/input/api

[image]

Comment: OMG YAS. You just saved my butt. Thank you so much. <3

Comment: awesome! I also needed to reinstall the dependencies. use "npm i"